# Any Postgres compatible ORM for Node.js?

Tags: postgresql, orm, node.js

I'm seeking for a good ORM for postgres under Node.js, one that supports declaration of relationships beetween models, and fields validation. I've searched during a long time and cannot get any satisfying results. Maybe someone can point me to a project I missed during my researches.
Thx.

Comment: Avoid ORMs. Use a postgres database driver

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[node-orm2](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2) looks good: supports association, validators, and mysql, postgres, and mongo (in beta)

**UPDATE**: The `node-orm2` package is no longer maintained. Possible alternatives include [bookshelf](https://github.com/bookshelf/bookshelf) or [sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize).

Comment: Currently, it does not feed PG with `DEFAULT` values on insertion when a value is not provided

Comment: @kolypto Looks like there's workaround for that. https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2/issues/391

Comment: @GregGuida, yes, now it has, but previously it did not

Answer (score 8):

[SequelizeJS](http://sequelizejs.com) - models, validation and migrations

[BookshelfJS](http://bookshelfjs.org/) - a promise based ORM looks quite promising

Comment: A note regarding sequelize - its implementations of associations are incredibly buggy and I could not get them to work at all in my project.

Comment: Bookshelf is wonderful.

Answer (score 6):

[JugglingDB](https://github.com/1602/jugglingdb) - multidatabase ORM inspired by activerecord and datamapper. Supports validations, hooks, relations. Works with: mysql, postgres, sqlite, memory, redis, mongodb, neo4j.

Not production ready now (march 2012), but growing fast. I plan stable release soon.

Comment: Currently, it assumes that your PK column is named `id`, and that's hardcoded

Answer (score 2):

Would recommend trying [Knex](http://knexjs.org/) for the database and [Bookshelf](http://bookshelfjs.org/) as an ORM on top of it (developed by same person). I'm using it with postgres, but supports SQLite, MySQL/MariaDB and Oracle (in alpha) too.

Very expressive promise-based API with `bluebird` behind it, knex has a well documented and great command line tool for making migrations, seed files etc. Bookshelf uses backbone models and collections as an inspiration, including the `.extend(..)` paradigm for inheritance, so picking it up is a breeze if you come from that world. So far, so good.

Comment: Have you an App tha use BS?,....how is its performance?

Comment: Yep, I use it in production. Performance is very good.

Answer (score 1):

[Missy](https://npmjs.org/package/missy) is a universal ORM for both SQL and NoSQL databases which is simple, flexible, well-documented and supports some fancy features that other ORMs are lacking

Answer (score 0):

ORM's are a little too slow for fast nature of node.js; plain database driver is fine, but a little tiring. That's for I do write something just between: [prego](https://github.com/sergeych/node-prego). It provides automatic statement preparation, migrations, simple models with associations, transactions and few utilities, all callback style and fast. Ideas/issues are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use this pair: [pg](https://npmjs.org/package/pg) (like a driver) and [light-orm](https://npmjs.org/package/light-orm) (like orm wrapper).

https://npmjs.org/package/pg

https://npmjs.org/package/light-orm

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.org/package/rdb
Simple, flexible mapper.
Transaction with commit and rollback.
Persistence ignorance - no need for explicit saving, everything is handled by transaction.
Eager or lazy loading.
Based on promises.
Well documented by (running) examples.