# ORM for postgresql/node.js

Tags: postgresql, node.js, orm

Node.js community is very active. There are at least several libraries for postgresql / ORM.

Right now - **march, 2012**, I am looking for the one which is mature enough, production ready and similar to Mongoose.

Please share if you had any **real** experiences with them.

Yes, I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041846/any-postgres-compatible-orm-for-node-js) question and dozen others.

Comment: Voting to close because this is a "find me the library" type of question. If there was more information provided about the different ORMs available, and why *you favored one over the other*, then I could see it having some merit.

Comment: Gosh, after digging deeper have seen some troubles, described mostly on blogs, with some nice looking libraries, and problems which were introduced after updates to newer versions. Please take a look on emphasis on a real life experiences with them.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked [jugglingdb](https://github.com/1602/jugglingdb)? Not production ready yet, but growing fast. I'm maintainer of this project, so feel free to ask any questions you have.

Comment: Hi @Anatoliy - how far out do you think a production-ready version is?  Is there a list of the big missing features or big bug fixes remaining anywhere?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi @MattHuggins. I think it's not so far - some relational magic, some more love to redis. And manual migrations for relational dbs - biggest missing feature. I will add roadmap section to readme.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this ORM:
https://npmjs.org/package/bookshelf (for big db)
https://npmjs.org/package/light-orm (for simple db)

Answer (score 0):

[**sails.js**](http://sailsjs.org) is the most popular MVC framework for node.js, and has support for postgres and a dozen other databases. sails.js is used in production for thousands of web applications, and is definitely worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

sequelizejs is an ORM that supports various SQL databases in nodejs ; currently this url this documentation : [Sequelizejs ORM For Nodejs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/getting-started/)

Answer (score 0):

[typeorm](http://typeorm.io) is an orm that supports various databases. this orm supports migrations(for me it is very important feature). Also it supports *typescript*